# Assessing possibilities in a random order

Tags: java

I'm currently writing a maze generator based on a modified depth-first search algorithm, but I'm running into trouble determining the cell to move to.
My question is: is there a simple way I can assess whether each neighboring cell is a valid space to move to in a random order? I know there are ways it can be done, but what I can think of involves looping until an acceptable solution is found, which is a poor practice I would like to avoid if possible.

My apologies if there is an obvious solution; I'm quite new to both programming and the site.

Comment: You could add all valid moves in an array then generate random number within the range [0, array.size - 1] i.e. a valid index, and then use one of the valid moves. No looping is required, extra book-keeping instead.

Comment: I don't know if I can do that due to how moves are checked; it's evaluated on the fly whether they are valid, and I don't have a data structure to store information about them. The goal is, basically, to check whether each move is valid in a random order without repeating checks.

Comment: Random sort the array, you can use `shuffle` I guess. Then just loop over them form start to finish.